# Understanding this usage of 「〜に変わって」

Tags: verbs

I am reading a selection from [A Japanese Reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0804816476) and am trying to figure out the meaning of this passage, especially the usage of 「これに変わって」:

> 古い行事のすべてをそのままに行うことは生活様式が異なってきた今日{こんにち}、無理であろうし、そのまま行う必要もない。新しい生活に即した行事が**これに変わって**生じてくることも意義があろう。

In the notes, it says that 「これ」 refers to 「古い行事のすべて」 but what trips me up is the use of 「に変わって」— does this mean “change into” as in 「新しい生活に即した行事」changes into 「古い行事のすべて」(which does not make much sense to me), or does 「に変わって」actually mean something like “instead” in this case? If so, is 「に変わって」a typo, or an acceptable replacement for 「に代わって・に替わって」(I admit that I am not 100% sure about which character is better here).

Comment: I'm not sure when the original passage was written, but in the light of today's orthography it should certainly be 代わる as you said.

Comment: I believe the passage was written in the 50s.

Comment: Then maybe the orthography was looser than now. Under the currently taught rule, I would definitely mark a cross on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a typo. It should be 代わって.